# [Kotlin]How can I retrieve only the file name excluding the path when listing files in a Directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm attempting to list all files inside of the directory excluding the path.(Ex: sdcard/Appfolder/file1.txt -> file1). I'm using this result to populate a spinner.

I have used "walktopdown" and "listFiles" to display all of the files in a specified directory. I was attempting to use a replace method to replace "sdcard/Appfolder/" and ".txt" with "" but realized I'm unable to do this with an array.

```
val dirlist = File("sdcard/Appfolder").walkTopDown().forEach { println(it) }
```

I also tried:

```
val f = File("sdcard/Appfolder")
val files = f.listFiles()
        println(files)
```

I'm using this to populate my spinner:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, files)
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
```

I'm attempting to just retrieve the file name excluding the path and extension. (Ex: File1, File2, File3)

Comment: File::getName() ?

Comment: Use `nameWithoutExtension`.

Comment: How can I incorporate nameWithoutExtension into the code to read out the dir.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code to achieve target: **name** return name with extension and **FilenameUtils** from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), remove extension. Hope this will help you. Thanks

```
File("sdcard/Appfolder").walkTopDown().forEach {
    println(FilenameUtils.removeExtension(it.name))
}
```

Comment: Currently attempting to learn how to incorporate the Apache Commons IO. With this method how am I able to populate my spinner.